# simple sql query highest sales

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables - Products and Sales

```
Products
prod_id
prod_nm



Sales
prod_id
cust_id
sls_dt
sls_amt
```

Write a query selecting ALL the products. For each product show total of sales amounts in the past 30 days or 0 if not sold in 30 day withoug using subqueries.

Since different RDBMS have different date functions, you can filter by date using the following pseudo code - sls_dt > now() - 30.

Im new to sql and im trying it like this as i found this online.

```
Select prod_id, prod_nm from(
Select sls_amt
From Sales) as t
Where t.rank = 1
```

However, this isnt' working. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `using the following pseudo code` ... date functions are highly RDBMS dependent, and a generic answer might not be helpful to anyone.  Which database are you using?

Comment: you can filter by date using the following pseudo code - sls_dt > now() - 30.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
select p.prod_id,
    p.prod_nm,
    sum(s.sls_amt)
from products p
left outer join Sales s on p.prod_id = s.prod_id
    and s.sls_dt > now() - 30
group by p.prod_id,
    p.prod_nm;
```